# "Disconnected Network Drive" in My Computer

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

We use VPN to connect to the work network. I have a mapped network drive that shows "Disconnected Network Drive" in My Computer immediately after I connect. While in this state I run a VBA routine:

```
Dim dr As String: dr = "F:\T\"
Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If Not fso.FolderExists(dr) Then
    Call fso.CreateFolder(dr)
End If
```

Even though the folder actually does exist, fso thinks it doesn't so it tries to create the folder and throws an error: Run-time error 76: Path not found. Of course it can't find it because it is in a disconnected state. Any other operations using that network drive will fail too.

So I open My Computer and manually double-click the network drive. It connects just fine and I no longer get the error when running the code again. But this is problematic. I need a solution in the code to automatically connect the network drive.

**Possible solution 1:** Just use the UNC path instead of mapped drive letter. The problem with that is that I don't know what the path is. Nor do I want to use UNC; the code needs to be flexible to work with wherever the drive maps to. It's policy from the brass.

**Possible solution 2:** Re-map the network drive using Net Use or WshNetwork. Again, this isn't really possible as I don't know what the UNC path is or will be.

**Possible solution 3:** [Connect using ShellExecute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27574806/2559297) While this would work, it isn't really palatable as it opens a window to explore the folder (could use SW_HIDE to avoid showing the window, but then how would I close it?). Furthermore it doesn't connect instantly. I would need a delay of uncertain length to make this work. Not a good answer. [MSDN ShellExecute Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx)

So is there a better solution? How do I connect the drive while waiting for it to return and throwing an error if not able to connect?

I need it to work for both VBScript and VBA.

Comment: Have you investigated using WMI to iterate the mapped drives and to connect the one you want? It shouldn't matter if the share that is mapped changes because you should be able to read that information and use it (the info is available, just Windows hasn't connected it yet).

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: [This previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8993155/109702) should help set you on your way. I think your better option would be to enumerate and find the correct mapped drive, then just determine its UNC path and use the UNC path directly - that way you don't have to reconnect the mapped drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slugster's suggestion to get the mapped UNC value is a good one. Here is my solution as adapted from [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/27047/copy-full-file-path-in-windows-xp/704374#704374) This works for VBScript and VBA.

```
Sub testget()
    Debug.Print getUNC("F:\T\")
End Sub

Function getUNC(dir)

    Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim sDrive: sDrive = fso.GetDriveName(dir)
    Set fso = Nothing

    Dim sMap: sMap = GetMappedDrive(sDrive)
    If sMap <> "" And sDrive <> sMap Then
        getUNC = Replace(dir, sDrive, sMap)
    Else
        getUNC = dir
    End If

End Function

Function GetMappedDrive(sDrive)
    Dim wshNetwork: Set wshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
    Dim oDrives: Set oDrives = wshNetwork.EnumNetworkDrives
    Dim i
    For i = 0 To oDrives.Count - 1 Step 2
        If UCase(oDrives.Item(i)) = UCase(sDrive) Then
            GetMappedDrive = oDrives.Item(i + 1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Set oDrives = Nothing
    Set wshNetwork = Nothing
End Function
```