# How can I troubleshoot a network share connection issue within a c# application?

Tags: c#, directory, console-application, network-shares

I can see a network share in explorer but when I use try to access it in my application I get "The network name cannot be found."

This is quite odd because the same server has other shares that I can access. For example:

```
string[] example_directories = new string[]{        
    Path.Combine(@"\\example01","vaqua"),
    Path.Combine(@"\\example01","vaqua-pub"),
    Path.Combine(@"\\example01","yesvirginiabeach"),
    Path.Combine(@"\\example01","yesvirginiabeach-pub")
};

// output username
Console.WriteLine("User: " + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

// output each response to Directory.Exists 
foreach (string directory in example_directories)
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(directory + " : " + Directory.GetCreationTime(directory));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(directory + " : " + e.Message.Trim());
    }

Console.Read();
```

Output:

```
User: domain\myusername
\\example01\vaqua : 10/22/2013 7:34:30 AM
\\example01\vaqua-pub : 10/22/2013 7:57:42 AM
\\example01\yesvirginiabeach : The network name cannot be found.
\\example01\yesvirginiabeach-pub : 4/4/2013 10:31:07 AM
```

I can see all four of those shares on \example01 in explorer but the `\example01\yesvirginiabeach` share just doesn't exist to my application.

These four shares all have the same permissions and I even print out my username to ensure the app is running with my creds.

I have had our admin re-share the directory and re-apply permissions to no avail.

### Solution: My admin misspelled the share name:

`\\example01\yesvirginiabeach` as `\\example01\yesvirgniabeach`.

Comment: Have a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472168/check-if-directory-exists-on-network-drive

Comment: Have you double-checked that the name `"yesvirginiabeach"` is correct? Make sure there's nothing crazy like a Unicode character that looks like an `"i"` but is really a different character.

Comment: Also maybe try [enumerating the shares](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091126/enumerating-network-shares-with-c-sharp) (see link for code) and see what your program can see.

Comment: @DavidNorris Please combine your comments into an answer. The folder name upon closer inspection was yesvirgniabeach. Ugh. Admins. I found this out by enumerating the shares. Thanks dude!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answered and resolved in comments above...)

Double-check that the name `"yesvirginiabeach"` is correct. Make sure there's nothing crazy like a Unicode character that looks like an `"i"` but is really a different character. (Solution turned out to be that someone misspelled the name of the folder as `"yesvirgniabeach"`.)

For similar problems one could try [enumerating the shares](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091126/enumerating-network-shares-with-c-sharp) to see what the program can see. There's also the `NET USE` command (open a Command Prompt and type `net use /help`; this tool shows all the shares currently being accessed and can open new shares from a command prompt, which sometimes gives useful status messages).