# check if url unc directory path exist

Tags: c#, unc

I am trying to check if the unc path folder (from web user input) was existing, here's my code:

```
Directory.Exists("file://localhost/c$/folderName/"); //this always return false
```

This is not  duplicate of : [how-to-quickly-check-if-unc-path-is-available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152647/how-to-quickly-check-if-unc-path-is-available.) since I was dealing with url unc path (using "//" backslash).

Comment: *`I already find the solutuion:`* then you may post an answer instead

Comment: I have added as answer, but you must never edit your Original Question to include the answer...

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the URI type. First, define a new URI using your UNC path

`Uri foo = new Uri("file://localhost/c$/folderName/");`

Then you need to just test it using

`Directory.Exists(foo.LocalPath);`.

This returns a boolean and will allow you to execute code based on the value.

So your whole code would be like below:

```
Uri foo = new Uri("file://localhost/c$/folderName/");

if (!Directory.Exists(foo.LocalPath))
{
  Debug.Log("UNC does not exist or is not accessible!");
}
else
{
  Debug.Log("UNC exists!");
}
```